# Backtesting a strategy for last 500 bars only

Tags: pine-script

Hello expert pine coders,

I am trying to backtest a strategy for last 500 bars only, Without having to manually change the input in settings everytime.

I appreciate if anyone could help me fix it. Kindly check my code below,

```
//@version=4
strategy("Simple alert strategy", overlay=true, max_lines_count=500, max_bars_back=5000, pyramiding=10000, commission_type=strategy.commission.percent, commission_value=0.015)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// BACKTESTING RANGE
 
// From Date Inputs
fromMinute = input(defval = 0, title = "From Minute", minval = 0, maxval = 59)
fromHour = input(defval = 0, title = "From Hour", minval = 0, maxval = 23)
fromDay = input(defval = 9, title = "From Day", minval = 1, maxval = 31)
fromMonth = input(defval = 11, title = "From Month", minval = 1, maxval = 12)
fromYear = input(defval = 2021, title = "From Year", minval = 1970)
 
// To Date Inputs
toDay = input(defval = 1, title = "To Day", minval = 1, maxval = 31)
toMonth = input(defval = 11, title = "To Month", minval = 1, maxval = 12)
toYear = input(defval = 2100, title = "To Year", minval = 1970)
 
// Calculate start/end date and time condition
startDate = timestamp(fromYear, fromMonth, fromDay, fromHour, fromMinute, 00)
finishDate = timestamp(toYear, toMonth, toDay, 00, 00)
time_cond = time >= startDate and time <= finishDate
 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


strategy.order("long", true, 1, when = close<open and time_cond, alert_message='Long')
strategy.order("short", false, 1, when = close>open and time_cond, alert_message='Short')
```

Regards,
Jakx.

Answer (score 1):

So, the idea is to substract two time values (one is the current time, the other one is your target) and divide that by the chart's resolution so you will get the number of bars between two times.

You can use two built-in variables for that.

> **timenow**: Current time in UNIX format [miliseconds].
> **time**: Current bar time in UNIX format [miliseconds].

Then create a variable (`bar_in_window` in our example) to track if the current bar is in this window.

After that, `and` this variable with your condition, so that in order to trigger your orders your condition `AND` this time window must be true.

Below is an example. Red triangles are where the time window is true (10 bars in this example). Green triangles are where I want to trigger my orders (whenever rsi is less than 70 during the last 10 bars).

```
//@version=5
indicator("Bars back", overlay=true)

bars_back = input.int(defval=10, title="Custom Bars back")

f_resInMiliseconds() => 
    _resInMiliseconds = 60000 * timeframe.multiplier * (
      timeframe.isseconds ? 1. / 60             :
      timeframe.isminutes ? 1.                  :
      timeframe.isdaily   ? 60. * 24            :
      timeframe.isweekly  ? 60. * 24 * 7        :
      timeframe.ismonthly ? 60. * 24 * 30.4375  : na)
      
bar_diff = int((timenow-time) / f_resInMiliseconds())
bar_in_window = bar_diff < bars_back
buy_condition = bar_in_window and (ta.rsi(close, 14) < 70)
plotshape(series=bar_in_window, style=shape.triangleup, color=color.red, size=size.small, location=location.belowbar)
plotshape(series=buy_condition, style=shape.triangledown, color=color.green, size=size.small, location=location.abovebar)
```

[image]

**NOTE:** This method would only work where the market is 24h open.

Comment: Yes its possible. I have used it before in an invite-only script. But now i want to use it in this script. You can find the invite-only script screenshot image here [Imgur screenshot](https://imgur.com/PtZt4bn)

A coder has hinted me to look at timenow variable. And can basically substract 500 * (number of miliseconds in a bar) and start backtesting from this timestamp.

Another coder has hinted me to loop 500 candles backwards. Yes its possible, I have used it. But don't know the code.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thinking about it now, it should be possible and challenge accepted :) Will edit my answer with some code later.

Comment: Thanks Baris. Looking forward to your code. Hope the settings looks like the screenshot [https://imgur.com/PtZt4bn](https://imgur.com/PtZt4bn)

Comment: Are you trading crypto?

Comment: Yes Baris and new to Pine script.

Comment: Okay, please see my answer now and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Its counting more than 10 bars. After 10 bars its still counting. Checkout the screenshot [https://imgur.com/4cXeFyk](https://imgur.com/4cXeFyk)

Comment: What's your ticker id and timeframe?

Comment: BTCUSDT, Chart type Heikin Ashi and timeframe 1 sec.

Comment: Did you try it on a minute or hourly chart? Sorry, I don't have a paid account anymore so cannot test this on a 1 sec chart.

Comment: I have tested in 1 minute chart also with 3 custom bars input and its still counting after 3 bars.

Comment: Hey Baris i have made a little trick to make your script work. I have installed an auto refresh page extension in chrome and set the refresh count to number of bars i want to backtest. For example if i want to test last 10 bars in 1 minute cart, I have set the refresh page count to 600 seconds. Its working bro. Its not exactly how i wanted but its close. Thanks for your time Baris. I really appriciate your effort and your valuble time for fixing my script. Where can i follow your work. Whats your Tradingview user id.

Comment: Hi @Jakx, glad you were able to fix your problem. I thought about the same thing but wanted to do all with the script. How was the behavior of that invite-only script you mentioned? I believe once you add your script to your chart, there is no way removing what is already plotted. So, for the very first time you add this script to your chart, it should work, but when a new bar opens, you will have a +1.

Comment: My Tradingview user id is vitruvius. You can also find my e-mail address if you go to my profile on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Your're right Baris the invite-only script is counting new bars also. I had only few minutes to try for first time so i hadn't checked for new bars. The second time i requested to try, I found its conting new bars also.